# how to prevent slide down from looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have made script with some menus with the submenu. i use `jQuery` for the submenu slide down (slidetoggle) animation when hover on the menu. so when i hover and then unhover the menu quickly for couple times, then i moved the cursor away from the menu, the slide down(slidetoggle) animation keep playing/looping equal how many times i hover the menu. what i want is how to make the jquery detect the next "hover" only when the previous slide animation is complete.

Plz help me with the code.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far, otherwise it is not possible to reasonably help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an try something like that:

```
$('.menu').on('hover', function(){
    $('.submenu').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Hard to answer, when no code is provided.

Comment: your answer fix this problem. i miss the 'stop'. btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `.animate()` function, you need to insert `.stop(true)` before `.animate()`, so it will look like this `.stop(true).animate()`;

You can use `.stop()` on any function with animations.

I guess that is your problem.